# Can I change an int variable value using the output of an int method in java

Tags: java

I understand the concept of taking an int value into a method which is effectively a copy of the int value, rather than the actual value and memory location.

Is there a way of changing the main integer value based on the result of the method?

If I return the int value to main can I do something like int num = int numIn where int numIn is the returned value.  If yes the can it be used for multiple methods returns, so that the main int value changes after each consecutive method return ?

Comment: What? Do you mean like `int num = someIntFunction(someOtherInt);`? Or reassigning, like `someOtherInt = someIntFunction(someOtherInt);`?

Comment: `int x = 10; x = computeNewValueFromOld(x);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the values of variables in methods, Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489913/changing-the-values-of-variables-in-methods-java)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Basic questions like this are better suited for google searches but yet, just reassign the value to the return value of your function... e.g. `x = myFunction(7); x = myNextFunction(8);` etc

Comment: See also the official tutorial on [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html), in particular the sections "Passing Information to a Method" and "Returning a Value From a Method". The tutorial is concise and well-written and will give you all the concepts you need to answer your question here.

Comment: Ok folk's I have a lot of research to do however thank you for your input. I maybe should have clarified I want to achieve this only using methods and not objects / classes, but all of your replies have given me lots of areas to investigate and learn. I am just coming to end of !st year of computer science so forgive my ignorance Thank you again

Comment: Dave Newton Thanks for your question.. The question actually refocused my brain Thanks again.. Not sure if that is a common thing when learning java but it worked for me.... opened a new door of ideas Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must begin [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

```
int i = 10;

private int add(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Initially the value of **i** is 10. But if you call-

```
i = add( 5, 10 );
```

The new value of **i** is now 15.