# How to use an output parameter in Java?

Tags: java, android, parameters

Could someone please give me some sample code that uses an output parameter in function? I've tried to Google it but just found it just in functions. I'd like to use this output value in another function.

The code I am developing intended to be run in Android.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Java passes by value; there's no `out` parameter like in C#.

You can either use `return`, or mutate an object passed **as** a reference (**by** value).

#### Related questions

- [Does Java have something like C#'s ref and out keywords?
  ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806545/does-java-have-something-like-cs-ref-and-out-keywords) (NO!)
- [Is Java pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) (NO!)

---

#### Code sample

```
public class FunctionSample {
    static String fReturn() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
    static void fArgNoWorkie(String s) {
        s = "What am I doing???"; // Doesn't "work"! Java passes by value!
    }
    static void fMutate(StringBuilder sb) {
        sb.append("Here you go!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = null;

        s = fReturn();
        System.out.println(s); // prints "Hello!"

        fArgNoWorkie(s);
        System.out.println(s); // prints "Hello!"

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        fMutate(sb);
        s = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(s); // prints "Here you go!"
    }

}
```

#### See also

- [What is meant by immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable)
- [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

---

As for the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824910/output-parameter-in-java/2825054#2825054) that OP needs help with, here's a typical solution of using a special value (usually `null` for reference types) to indicate success/failure:

Instead of:

```
String oPerson= null;
if (CheckAddress("5556", oPerson)) {
   print(oPerson); // DOESN'T "WORK"! Java passes by value; String is immutable!
}

private boolean CheckAddress(String iAddress, String oPerson) {
   // on search succeeded:
   oPerson = something; // DOESN'T "WORK"!
   return true;
   :
   // on search failed:
   return false;
}
```

Use a `String` return type instead, with `null` to indicate failure.

```
String person = checkAddress("5556");
if (person != null) {
   print(person);
}

private String checkAddress(String address) {
   // on search succeeded:
   return something;
   :
   // on search failed:
   return null;
}
```

This is how [`java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) works, for example: it returns `instanceof String` (perhaps an empty string!), until it returns `null` to indicate end of "search".

This is not limited to a reference type return value, of course. The key is that there has to be some special value(s) that is never a valid value, and you use that value for special purposes.

Another classic example is [`String.indexOf`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29): it returns `-1` to indicate search failure.

> *Note*: because Java doesn't have a concept of "input" and "output" parameters, using the `i-` and `o-` prefix (e.g. `iAddress`, `oPerson`) is unnecessary and unidiomatic.

---

#### A more general solution

If you need to return several values, usually they're related in some way (e.g. `x` and `y` coordinates of a single `Point`). The best solution would be to encapsulate these values together. People have used an `Object[]` or a `List<Object>`, or a generic `Pair<T1,T2>`, but really, your own type would be best.

For this problem, I recommend an immutable `SearchResult` type like this to encapsulate the `boolean` and `String` search results:

```
public class SearchResult {
   public final String name;
   public final boolean isFound;

   public SearchResult(String name, boolean isFound) {
      this.name = name;
      this.isFound = isFound;
   }
}
```

Then in your search function, you do the following:

```
private SearchResult checkAddress(String address) {
  // on address search succeed
  return new SearchResult(foundName, true);
  :
  // on address search failed
  return new SearchResult(null, false);
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
SearchResult sr = checkAddress("5556");
if (sr.isFound) {
  String name = sr.name;
  //...
}
```

If you want, you can (and probably should) make the `final` immutable fields non-`public`, and use `public` getters instead.

Comment: I also need to get boolean return value. because some person values will be null and i wanna know whether there is any address or not. So I need to get back two values - boolean and string. That's why I wanna use passing by value.

Comment: is there no ref aswell then?  Thats a major pain given that you can only have 1 class per file + the fact that there are no properties in java.  It forces you to use extra classes but makes them cumbersome to write :(

Comment: @JonnyLeeds no need to have 1 class per file, you can use inner classes.

Comment: @JonnyLeeds one PUBLIC class per file I thought, plenty of private, package level, protected and indeed inner classes are ok.

Comment: Btw the `Pair` class is part of `javafx.util`, which is not standard included anymore. On how to install see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11

Answer (score 8):

Java does not support output parameters. You can use a return value, or pass in an object as a parameter and modify the object.

Answer (score 6):

You can either use:

- return X.  this will return only one value.
- return object.  will return a full object. For example your object might include X, Y, and Z values.
- pass array. arrays are passed by reference. i.e. if you pass array of integers, modified the array inside the method, then the original code will see the changes.

Example on passing Array.

```
void methodOne{
    int [] arr = {1,2,3};
    methodTwo(arr);
    ...//print arr here
}
void methodTwo(int [] arr){
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
         arr[i]+=3;
    }
}
```

This will print out: 4,5,6.

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround a generic "ObjectHolder" can be used. See code example below.

The sample output is:

```
name: John Doe
dob:1953-12-17
name: Jim Miller
dob:1947-04-18
```

so the Person parameter has been modified since it's wrapped in the Holder which is passed by value - the generic param inside is a reference where the contents can be modified - so actually a different person is returned and the original stays as is.

```
/**
 * show work around for missing call by reference in java
 */
public class OutparamTest {

 /**
  * a test class to be used as parameter
  */
 public static class Person {
   public String name;
     public String dob;
     public void show() {
      System.out.println("name: "+name+"\ndob:"+dob);
   }
 }

 /**
  * ObjectHolder (Generic ParameterWrapper)
  */
 public static class ObjectHolder<T> {
    public ObjectHolder(T param) {
     this.param=param;
    }
    public T param;
 }

 /**
  * ObjectHolder is substitute for missing "out" parameter
  */
 public static void setPersonData(ObjectHolder<Person> personHolder,String name,String dob) {
    // Holder needs to be dereferenced to get access to content
    personHolder.param=new Person();
    personHolder.param.name=name;
    personHolder.param.dob=dob;
 } 

  /**
   * show how it works
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Person jim=new Person();
    jim.name="Jim Miller";
    jim.dob="1947-04-18";
    ObjectHolder<Person> testPersonHolder=new ObjectHolder(jim);
    // modify the testPersonHolder person content by actually creating and returning
    // a new Person in the "out parameter"
    setPersonData(testPersonHolder,"John Doe","1953-12-17");
    testPersonHolder.param.show();
    jim.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430479/how-do-i-use-an-equivalent-to-c-reference-parameters-in-java/431152#431152 Answer: Simulating references with wrappers ...

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the value passed in different classes that might be helpful doing the trick, check below for more real example:

```
  class Ref<T>{

    T s;

    public void set(T value){
        s =  value;
    }

    public T get(){
        return s;
    }

    public Ref(T value) {
        s = value;
    }
}


class Out<T>{

    T s;

    public void set(T value){
        s =  value;
    }
    public T get(){
        return s;
    }

    public Out() {
    }
}

public static void doAndChangeRefs (Ref<String> str, Ref<Integer> i, Out<String> str2){
    //refs passed .. set value
    str.set("def");
    i.set(10);

    //out param passed as null .. instantiate and set 
    str2 = new Out<String>();
    str2.set("hello world");
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Ref<Integer>  iRef = new Ref<Integer>(11);
        Out<String> strOut = null; 
        doAndChangeRefs(new Ref<String>("test"), iRef, strOut);
        System.out.println(iRef.get());
        System.out.println(strOut.get());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not accurate ---> "...* pass array. arrays are passed by reference. i.e. if you pass array of integers, modified the array inside the method.

Every parameter type is passed by value in Java. Arrays are object, its object reference is passed by value.

This includes an array of primitives (int, double,..) and objects.  The integer *value* is changed by the methodTwo() but it is still the same arr object reference, the methodTwo() cannot add an array element or delete an array element. methodTwo() cannot also, create a new array then set this new array to arr. If you really can pass an array by reference, you can replace that arr with a brand new array of integers.

Every object passed as parameter in Java is passed by value, no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I use passing in an object as a parameter. My Android code is below

```
    String oPerson= null;
    if (CheckAddress("5556", oPerson))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, 
                "It's Match! " + oPerson,                   
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private boolean CheckAddress(String iAddress, String oPerson)
{
    Cursor cAddress = mDbHelper.getAllContacts();
    String address = "";        
    if (cAddress.getCount() > 0) {
        cAddress.moveToFirst();
        while (cAddress.isAfterLast() == false) {
            address = cAddress.getString(2).toString();
            oPerson = cAddress.getString(1).toString(); 
            if(iAddress.indexOf(address) != -1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, 
                        "Person : " + oPerson,                  
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println(oPerson);
                cAddress.close();
                return true;                    
            }
            else cAddress.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cAddress.close();
    return false;
}
```

The result is

> Person : John
>
> It's Match! null

Actually, "It's Match! John"

Please check my mistake.

Comment: You passed the object, but you didn't mutate it (which you couldn't anyway, since `String` is immutable). You tried to assign a new reference to it (`oPerson = ...`) which doesn't work (just like `fArgNoWorkie`), since Java is pass by value. Look at my code example and try to understand it.

Comment: In this case, instead of returning `boolean`, you can return a `String`, which is `null` if there's no match.

Comment: Hi, polygenelubricants, I tested it with oPerson. I got null. I edited my previous code above. Please check it again. Thank you.